# Creating a search application in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a web application for my team.This application will be handling the data of the FAQ's related to my team activities.The application should allow the team members to add a question and the answer for the question.The answer may contain pictures for more clarification.Also it will facilitate a search option for searching the FAQ.I am planning to use a simple word document to store the data.I will be using asp.net MVC for this.I am stuck with two question

1. Is it possible to append the data in a word document?
2. Is it possible to search data and show the approximate match?

How to do this in asp.net MVC?

Comment: are you going to write it with php?

Comment: Why do you use Word as your database? You gonna go through hell in order to fetching specific data from Word, Ex: fetching a question and its relative answer

Comment: You are using the wrong tools for the job. Look for alternatives, what you're suggesting makes all my alarm bells go off. There are plenty of documentation tools available out there.

Comment: i dont want to use tools like alfresco.

Comment: DoanCuong What database are you suggesting then?